# The uploaded file exceeds!

Tags: wp-admin, uploads

I have configured Wordpress locally on my system(Windows 7 professional). I want to upload a theme to test it, but whenever I tried to upload the theme with more the 1MB. It shows me the error which read as:

**The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.**

As per stackexchange's previous question answers I made a text file renamed as php.ini with code and pasted in Wp-admin folder but still it is not working. The added code to the file is mentioned below:

```
memory_limit = 32M
upload_max_filesize = 32M
post_max_size = 32M
file_uploads = On
```

but still getting the same error. What to do?

Answer (score 1):

A `php.ini` in your WordPress directory has no effect if PHP is running as a service, not per CGI or FastCGI.

Find the `php.ini` in your PHP installation path, adjust the values there and restart PHP and your web server.

So … until here this was off topic because general PHP questions belong to Stack Overflow. ;)

But:

```
memory_limit = 32M
```

That's *very* low for WordPress. Just think about an image that has to be resized – this will probably not work if the image is rather big. Translation is rather expensive too. I don't many German blogs which are able to run with such a low value.

Set this value to 128M or more.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I understand this should be a stackoverflow question, but since you answer it and am facing the problem with wordpress so I posted here. I searched for the php.ini file in my wordpress folder but can't find php.ini file. I am trying to upload a theme to my blog. Please guide.

Comment: The `php.ini` is **not** in your WordPress directory, is is in your PHP install path.

Comment: Thanks again for mentioning that. I figured out the file in wampserver, but still after updating the file to 256M am getting the same error while uploading a 3mb theme.